# HTML/JQuery: Button submits once when it shouldn't at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using jQuery to allow the form to submit, so I don't want the form to submit on it's own.

Here's my form:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" id="signform">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button id="signbtn" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Here's my JQuery code:

```
var signingIn = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signbtn').click(function() {
        if (signingIn) return;
        signingIn = true;

        var img = $('<img id="loader" style="padding-left: 10px;" src="loader.gif"/>');
        $(this).after(img);

        var data = $('signform').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/logs',
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            done: function() {
                $('#loader').remove();
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Now when I go to the url: website.com/index.html and click Sign in, it refreshes the page (what I don't want at all) and goes to website.com/index.html? - Now when I click it again, nothing happens (exactly what I want all the time so my added elements through jQuery isn't lost).

Comment: Wheres your jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use jQuery ajax call like so:

```
$(document).on('click','button#signbtn', function(){

        var $form = $('form#signform');
        var url = $form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               enctype: 'mutipart/form-data',
               url: url,
               data: $form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data){// whatever you want your code to do on success}
             })

        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
```

Comment: What is the difference between $(button).click and $(document).on?

Comment: I like to use $(document).on because it will handle events on dom objects that are newly created, while $(button).click will only handle events for dom objects that initially load on the page. For instance if you created your form with javascript, then $(button).click would not work, but $(document).on would. If however your form was not made via javascript, $(button).click will work just fine.

Comment: Or wait, I did this: http://pastebin.com/ME0pZzVi. On first click, it works and the page isn't refreshed, on second one, it is refreshed, then not, then refreshed, etc..

Comment: return false needs to be immediately after the ajax call, inside the if statement.

Comment: Eh this is getting weird. Now if I comment the ajax part, it works the exact way I want it, page is never refreshed. If I uncomment the ajax part, it's always refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

  $( '#signform' ).submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: $(this).attr( 'action' ),
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(result) {

         // Do something on success

       }

     });

  });

});
```

Comment: Also tried this, same behaviour as return false. Check above.

Comment: Ok, I don't completly understand what do you want to achive but you could look at my login system at [M Design & Development](http://mdesdev.net) you have login in the top bar, username: test / password: test , is that what you're looking for or...BTW my script refreshes page back to index.php